# Why is multiprocessing system needs process scheduling?

Tags: process, operating-system

According to my understanding one operation is operated by one CPU. And, multiprocessing systems have multiple CPUs. That is, multiprocessing systems can work on multiple tasks at the same time.

But, in multiprocessing systems, only one process is in working state at a point of time.
And processes are alternately performed by process scheduling. 
So multiprocessing systems can work on multiple processes at the same time.

Why multiprocessing systems that have multiple CPUs use process scheduling and perform only one process at once by using one CPU?

Why don't multiple CPUs perform multiple processes at the same time?

Comment: Who said they don't?

Comment: 'in multiprocessing systems, only one process is in working state at a point of time' - who told you that?

Comment: In general, if a system has X cores, then up to X threads can be running at any instant.  If there is more than one running thread,  those threads may belong to different processes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why multiprocessing systems that have multiple CPUs use process scheduling and perform only one process at once by using one CPU?

Most systems these days use THREAD scheduling; not process scheduling. There are still some Eunuchs variants that still schedule processes but most have switched to threads.

> Why don't multiple CPUs perform multiple processes at the same time?

They do. They also execute multiple threads in the same process at the same time.